# Add FLTK library in CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, cmake, fltk

I need to add FLTK as a dependency in my CMakeLists.txt. 
The library based in `<project_root/dist/FLTK>`.
It was built in `<project_root/dist/FLTK/build>` directory.

This is my hole config:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

set(DIST_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dist")
set(FLTK "${DIST_DIR}/FLTK")

if(NOT IS_DIRECTORY ${FLTK}) 
  message("Starting add FLTK library...")
  execute_process(COMMAND git submodule add https://github.com/IngwiePhoenix/FLTK.git "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dist/FLTK") 
  execute_process(COMMAND git submodule update --init --recursive)
endif()

link_directories("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dist/FLTK/build")
add_library(fltk "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dist/FLTK/build/lib")


add_definitions(-Werror -std=c++17)
add_executable(main main.cpp)
```

What is wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Your CMakeLists.txt has several problems. The most obvious one is the use of `add_library` which is for building libraries not for linking (if this is what you wanted to do). A good starting point could be the [CMake tutorial](https://cmake.org/cmake-tutorial/#s2).

Comment: "It was built in <project_root/dist/FLTK/build> directory." - Has the library **already** been built, or it is *your code* (`CMakeLists.txt`) which should build it?

Comment: yes, @Tsyvarev, it was built

Comment: Have you seen the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774593/cmake-link-to-external-library about linking the library?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to `havogt` and `Tsyvarev` I found the solution! I am not expert in CMake but maybe this help to some one:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -g -std=c++17")

set(DIST_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dist")
set(FLTK "${DIST_DIR}/FLTK")

if(NOT IS_DIRECTORY ${FLTK}) 
  message("Starting add FLTK library...")
  execute_process(COMMAND git clone https://github.com/fltk/fltk.git ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dist/FLTK)
  execute_process(COMMAND make -C ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dist/FLTK)
endif()

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dist/FLTK)

add_executable(keyplay ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp)

find_library(LibFltk libfltk.a PATHS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dist/FLTK/lib/)

if(APPLE)
  find_library(COCOA Cocoa)
endif()

target_link_libraries(keyplay ${LibFltk} ${COCOA})
```